# How to compare two different rotation matrices and euler angles for head pose estimation

Tags: c++, opencv

I am working on face head estimation using dlib and opencv from a saved video.

I am able to get head rotation matrix and euler angle using opencv solvepnp function in each frame. My question is how can I get the angle difference between 2 consecutive frame based on rotation matrix or euler angle matrix?

```
std::vector<cv::Point3d> object_pts; //generic 3D world coordinate
std::vector<cv::Point2d> image_pts; //dlib landmark points
cv::Mat rotation_vec;    //3 x 1
cv::Mat rotation_mat;    //3 x 3 R
cv::Mat translation_vec;

//calc pose
cv::solvePnP(object_pts, image_pts, cam_matrix, dist_coeffs, rotation_vec, translation_vec);

//calc euler angle
cv::Rodrigues(rotation_vec, rotation_mat);
cv::hconcat(rotation_mat, translation_vec, pose_mat);
cv::decomposeProjectionMatrix(pose_mat, out_intrinsics, out_rotation, out_translation, cv::noArray(), cv::noArray(), cv::noArray(), euler_angle);
```

This is example of rotation and euler angle matrices from two frames:

```
First frame : 
rotation_mat: [0.9808042880813987, -0.00560492255811192, -0.194914169121329;
 -0.009358357320917634, 0.9970819362297282, -0.07576300939528717;
 0.1947700429465335, 0.07613276093439612, 0.9778897857545662]

Euler_angle[4.451733321076386;
 -11.23129045806711;
 -0.5466718623384634]

Second frame: 
rotation_mat: [0.9821961040283421, -0.005362175244554571, -0.1877819488347928;
 -0.01108060484669302, 0.9961985559469002, -0.08640403535450306;
 0.1875314198415228, 0.0869464444699003, 0.9784029243447022]

Euler_angle[5.078288701210371;
 -10.80875560893563;
 -0.6463525542012101]
```

My goal is to find one pose as a baseline and compare other head pose from each frame to find how much it deviates from the baseline.

Best regards.

Comment: I would never compare Euler angles. They might be ambiguous. Instead, I would evaluate the 4x4 matrices directly. Assuming, they contain really only translation and rotation: Multiply the upperleft 3x3 submatrix of the first with the transposed (i.e. inverted) upperleft 3x3 submatrix of the second to get the difference of orientations. As well you can subtract the last column of second from last column of first to get the difference of translations. (If the most lower right element is not 1 you have to divide the other 3 by this value. However, for pure TR this shouldn't happen.)

Comment: Most of the 3d/graphics libs I know store 4x4 matrices transposed. To check this, just look at the values of a matrix with translation only. If the last column shows translation, it's not transposed. If it's the last row, then it is.

Comment: Looking again at your code, I realized T and R are already separated in your case. (My fault.) Forget what I told about 4x4 matrices - the rest should be OK. Once, you have a Rd = R1 * R2^T, what to do with it. You still could decompose it to Euler angles but, may be, decomposition to axis/angle might be interesting as well.

Comment: Thanks @Scheff for the helpful insight. I just want to clarify: after we decompose Rd, we get the angle difference in x,y,z axis. Is this value the same as subtracting 2 euler angles from each frame or it could be different because comparing euler angle might be ambiguous as you stated. Please kindly elaborate.

Comment: The 3x3 rotation matrix is (looking closer) nothing else than 3 vectors with the values of the 3 rotated unit axes. Concerning the orientation, there's only one unique 3x3 matrix which represents this. (The weakness is the limitation to one ful circle. You cannot distinguish -90 about x from +270. That's why I said orientation instead of rotation.) This in mind: changing D * R1 = R2 to D = R2 * R1^-1, you can compute the difference of two (rotation) matrices. Inverse of a rotation matrix is just its transposed. (How nice.) D is (obviously) a rotation matrix as well. Does this help further?

Comment: Yes, this helps me a lot. I just realized that euler angle is not even a vector, so adding or subtracting 2 euler angles is not an option. Thanks again @Scheff

Comment: Sounds, like you got it. ;-) It's on your own how you decompose the rotation difference D. You might decompose into Euler angles. Beside of this, every rotation matrix might be build from (and hence, I assume, can be decomposed into) _one_ axis/angle representation. Concerning the latter, I googled but got lost in the numerous hits concerning Euler angles. There is yet another common representation as Quaternion but that's not that intuitive...